# Failed to parse date ["2021-05-06 15:24:26 CEST"]: Invalid time zone indicator ' ', but timezone exists

Tags: php, date, kotlin, format

I am struggling a bit with the date format patterns in Kotlin.
I have a PHP backend, that formats dates in the format `"Y-m-d H:i:s T"`, which as you might guess from the title, results in:  ["2021-05-06 15:24:26 CEST"]. As you can see there is also a timezone, in our case "CEST".
However, my Kotlin app tells me, that the " " is an invalid timezone format.
I am pretty confused of the different patterns used and it took me a while to get a grip, so it is possible, that there is an error inside of the pattern.
In Kotlin I have the following GSONBuilder:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z").create()
```

I also tried the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s z"` and `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"`, but it didn´t work either. Is there an error in my pattern? I mean, the timezone is part of the result arriving. If yes, what would be the correct pattern?

Note: Debugger tells me an index out of bounds-exception, if that might help.

EDIT:
Shortened exception stack:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app, PID: 27254
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 2021-05-11 10:07:04 CEST
        at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:151)
        at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.read(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:128)
        at 
...
com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
...
retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:40)
...
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:243)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at 
...
     Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["2021-05-11 10:07:04 CEST"]: Invalid time zone indicator ' '
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:274)
        at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:149)
        at 
... (Same as first stack trace)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid time zone indicator ' '
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.util.ISO8601Utils.parse(ISO8601Utils.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:149) 
        at 
... (same as first stack trace)
```

Edit 2:
Since CEST is indeed no valid Java ID, I changed the PHP format from `"Y-m-d H:i:s T"` to `"Y-m-d H:i:s e"`, which now results in "2021-05-11 10:07:04 Europe/Berlin" and is indeed a valid timezone identifier according to cutikos comment.
However, the error is still the same.

Comment: I don't think `CEST` is a valid id https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/

Comment: Well, it was produced by PHP, so it should be

Comment: Can you post your debugger error message?

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been pretty simple:
The java format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" only accepts the numbers "00a0" format, so the correct PHP format would be:
`"Y-m-d H:i:s O"`

Hope this helps another person, struggling with dateformat conventions.